# Show symbol when over 100%

Tags: html, angularjs

When the value `{{reservoir}}`is more than 100 to show an icon if less than 100 show the values.

```
 <div class="water-box-label text-center" ng-if="reservoir>100"> 
    <div>
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
    </div>
    {{reservoir}}
    <h5>
        <p>{{reservoir_value}} m&sup3</p>
    </h5>
 </div>
```

Controller

```
 $scope.reservoir = $scope.updateWaterLevel(value, "watertank");
 $scope.reservoir_value = ($scope.reservoir.split("%")[0]*1000)/100;
 $scope.updateWaterLevel = function (value, elementID) {
    var waterBox = document.getElementById(elementID);
    waterBox.style.height = value.INFO + '%';
    if (value.INFO < 15) {
        waterBox.style.background = '#c0392b';
    }else if(value.INFO > 100){
        waterBox.style.height = 0;
    } else {
        waterBox.style.background = '#3498db';
    }
    return value.INFO + ' %';
};
```

Comment: Show the controller that handles this logic.

Comment: So you have an `ng-if` already. What is the specific problem? What are expected results?

Comment: When the tank is over 100% should appear the icon `<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>` but shows nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `$scope.updateWaterLevel` is called before it is assigned. If you want to keep it at the bottom of the controller, change it to a function declaration which will be hoisted and can be called from the top of your controller.

```
$scope.updateWaterLevel = updateWaterLevel;
...
function updateWaterLevel(value, elementID) {
    ...
}
```

Second, the `ng-if` is comparing a number 100 against a string `reservoir` initialised as `value.INFO + ' %'`. Try leaving `reservoir` as a number and add the '%' in the view.

Comment: Ive made your suggestion as leaving the reservoir has int, and add the '%' in the view the result is the same, if it was in the previous version, it show nothing

Comment: What about ensuring the $scope.updateWaterLevel is assigned before it is called? It would help if you create a plunker or jsfiddle

Comment: Doesnt work, with your suggestion, continues to appear blank, also tried to use ng-show instead of ng-if but it doesnt recognizes the variable
`<div class="water-box-label text-center">
  <div ng-show="waterLevelR1_1>100%">
 <h5><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle text-top">Erro</i></h5></div>
{{waterLevelR1_1}}<h5><p>{{waterLevelR1_1_value}} m&sup3</p></h5></div>`

Comment: Try ng-show="waterLevelR1_1>100" , and if you want to show a %, do it here: {{waterLevelR1_1}} %

Comment: Worked using only the number